# JPA Clave compuesta para .find()

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, búsquedas

tengo una entidad con claves compuestas, como puedo hacer el .find()

```
Obj p = XPersistence.getManager().find(Obj.class, ??clave)??;

p.setCampoDesc("hola");

XPersistence.getManager().getTransaction().commit();
```

la clase tiene

```
    @Id
    @Column(name="xxxx", columnDefinition="smallint")   
    private Integer xxxx;
    @Id
    @Column(name="xxx", columnDefinition="char(5)",length=5)
    private String xxxx;
    @Id 
    @Column(name="xxxx", columnDefinition="char(5)",length=5)
    private String xxx;
    @Id
    @Column(name="xxxx", columnDefinition="char(7)",length=7)
    private String xxx;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta de @pablo es correcta. Sólo escribo esta respuesta para aportar más información del posible uso de las anotaciones de JPA.

Lo primero, para implementar una clave primaria compuesta (a partir de ahora PK), es necesario tener una clase a parte marcada como `@Embeddable`. Vamos a suponer para nuestros ejemplos que tenemos una entidad llamada `A` que tiene una PK compuesta por dos enteros, tal que así:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tmp_a")
public class A {
    @EmbeddedId
    private PK_A clave;
    //¿Como pongo los atributos de la PK en la clase?

    private String atributoNoDeClavePrimaria;
}

@Embeddable
public class PK_A {
    public int id1, id2;
    //getters, setters, hashCode y equals
}
```

La estructura de la tabla sería la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_a(
    id1 INT NOT NULL,
    id2 INT NOT NULL,
    atributoNoDeClavePrimaria VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id1, id2)
);
```

Ahora bien, ¿y si yo decido que no me gustan los nombres *`id1`* e *`id2`*? Quiero, para que todo quede más claro en el código Java, llamarlos `codProducto` y `codFactura`. Estos nombres ya no son los mismos que en la base de datos, ¿cómo puedo decirle a JPA que esos atributos son en realidad la PK de la tabla? Para ello tenemos la etiqueta `@MapsId(nombre_de_atributo)`. En nuestro ejemplo, la clase `A` quedaría así:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tmp_a")
public class A {
    @EmbeddedId
    private PK_A clave;

    @Column(name="id1")
    @MapsId("codProducto")
    private int codProducto; 
    //Notese que aqui tambien he cambiado el nombre de la columna

    @Column(name="id2")
    @MapsId("codFactura")
    private int codFactura;

    ...
}
```

Pero todavía podemos mejorar. Ya que hemos puesto como ejemplo productos y facturas, podemos poner una columna de una PK como una relacion muchos a uno, lo que nos permitiria traernos los objetos con la relacion (suponemos que hay creadas dos entidades `Producto` y `Factura`):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tmp_a")
public class A {
    @EmbeddedId
    private PK_A clave;

    @JoinColumn(name="id1", insertable=true, updatable=true)
    @MapsId("codProducto")
    @ManyToOne
    private Producto producto;

    @JoinColumn(name="id2", insertable=true, updatable=true)
    @MapsId("codFactura")
    @ManyToOne
    private Factura factura;

    ...
}
```

Y todo sin tener que escribir más anotaciones que `@Embeddable` en la clase que representa la PK.

Answer (score 2):

Usa una clave primaria compuesta, implementada en una clase concreta. Por ejemplo:

```
@Entity
public class MiClase{
    @EmbeddedId
    private MiClavePrimaria miClavePrimaria;
    @Column(...)
    private String campo1;
    ...
    @Column(...)
    private String campoN;
}

@Embeddable
public class MiClavePrimaria {

    @Column
    private String campoClavePrimaria1;
    ...
    @Column
    private String campoClavePrimariaN;

}
```

Y para hacer el find:

```
MiClavePrimaria clave = new MiClavePrimaria();
clave.setCampoClavePrimaria1(valor1);
...
clave.setCampoClavePrimariaN(valorN);
MiClase p = XPersistence.getManager().find(MiClase.class, clave );
```

Comment: En realidad, no hace falta poner la anotación @column la clase que representa la clave primaria

Comment: Sí haría falta si el nombre de la propiedad no coincidiera con el nombre de la columna en BD.

Comment: Es posible marcar una propiedad de una entidad con la anotación `@MapsId([nombre_de_propiedad])`. Ese nombre de propiedad es el de la clave primaria que utilizas, que puede llamarse como quieras.

Comment: ¿Con esa anotación puedes asociar cada propiedad de la clave primaria a un nombre de columna determinado?

Comment: He escrito la respuesta con información adicional por si interesa ver algun detalle extra

Comment: y como puedo actualizar el un campo de la base de datos?

Comment: @Adrian.Aguirre Perdona, no he entendido la pregunta. ¿Qué duda tienes?